# I want to do this equation even if some values ​are not entered, a result appears

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I want this to return a value even if some values do not exist

```
TO_CHAR((100-NVL(CO2+CO+MOIST+NH3_PPM+NH3+CH4+N2+AR,0)),'99.09') as "H2",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, it looks as if you wanted multiple NVLs:

```
TO_CHAR((100 - (
                NVL(CO2    , 0) +
                NVL(CO     , 0) +
                NVL(MOIST  , 0) +
                NVL(NH3_PPM, 0) +
                NVL(NH3    , 0) + 
                NVL(CH4    , 0) +
                NVL(N2     , 0) +
                NVL(AR     , 0)
               ), '99.09') AS h2
```